# How to avoid empty date getting converted to DateTime.Min value when saving to database? Entity Frameworks

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, formview

I have a form with text box for date input. If I Provide date everything is fine. If I don't provide date (I leave it empty), DateTime.min (1/1/0001) value is sent. And this causes error: **The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value**

My date property is defined as nullable:

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> InstallDate { get; set; }
```

What I want is null value to be written to database if I don't provide date.
I know I could in my update method check for 1/1/0001 and send null, but, do I have to do that? **Is there a way around this problem?** Thanks

**EDIT:**

**I solved the problem adding code below into my update method:**

```
tank.InstallDate = tank.InstallDate == DateTime.MinValue ? null : tank.InstallDate;
```

So my code looks like this:

```
public void UpdateTank(Tank tank)
{
    using (RetailFuelEntities ctx = new RetailFuelEntities())
    {
        tank.InstallDate = tank.InstallDate == DateTime.MinValue ? null : tank.InstallDate;
        ctx.Tanks.Attach(tank);
        ctx.Entry(tank).State = EntityState.Modified;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Here is my ObjectDataSource:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetTank"
                            TypeName="DataAccess.Fuel.EF4.Tanks" DataObjectTypeName="DataAccess.Fuel.EF4.Tank"
                            DeleteMethod="DeleteTank" InsertMethod="InsertTank" UpdateMethod="UpdateTank">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBoxTankId" Name="TankId" PropertyName="Text"
                                    Type="String" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I wonder if null checking can be avoided.

Comment: Please provide more code. Is this the auto-generated property from EF? From where to you set this property and how? Try to traverse the whole route in your question, from form (WinForms, WPF?) to database (column type, null allowed?).

Comment: This property is generated by DbContext generator. In my SQL table, InstallDate field is of type: Shared.DateAndTime:smalldatetime. So, in my FormView I have TextBox where I am supposed to provide Install Date. My problem is, once I click Update button, if I don't put anything in textbox, my Update method (that receives object being updated) has myObject.InstallDate equal to DateTime.MinValue. I simply want it to be null and don't understand why it is converted this way.

Comment: there is not really much code here... there is FormView, ObjectDataSource which is set (in my opinion) properly to perform Select, Update, Insert and Delete. Update, Insert and Delete for parameter are receiving object that FormView is bound to. Except Update method, I didn't write any custom code after DbContext generator generated all my objects.

Comment: Your problem is not in EF or DB, it is between your `FormView` and `tank` object. How do you read the `TextBox` value and set it in your `tank`?

Comment: Not much code at all. See my ObjectDataSource in the last edit I made. Basically, when update button on FormView is pressed, UpdateTank method is called and whole object is passed to it. Didn't do any transformations or anything special.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your UI control (`FormView`) doesn't convert an empty string to `null`, but instead to `DateTime.MinValue`. Your property happily accepts this value, because it's a valid date after all.

The solution can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/12793ce2-50fc-4cb3-9df8-db54dbf4eb8b/). Basically, there's a parameter attribute specifically for this case and it's called `ConvertEmptyStringToNull`.

Comment: I see what you are saying. In my case Update method receives object as parameter, so I can't (or I don't know how to) specify what I need inside UpdateParameters. I tried this and of course it was ignored: <asp:Parameter Name="InstallDate" Type="DateTime" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"  />. I was hoping for some general ConvertEmptyStringToNull property that is applicable to whole FormView. Thanks.

Comment: Well there's also this article, it mentions something about setting `ConvertNullToDBNul` in the ObjectDataSource -  http://www.donkitchen.com/2007/07/15/formview-and-objectdatasource-with-nullable-types/ .